# Событие изменения в jquery

Tags: jquery

Вот такой пример, http://jsfiddle.net/3sV3a/34/

При клике на ссылку меняется значение списка, но не работает "алерт" когда скрипт меняет значение списка.

Ка заставить jquery видеть что он сам поменял значение в списке?

Answer (score 2):

Можно принудительно вызвать событие onchange: http://jsfiddle.net/copist/3sV3a/36/

```
$('#select_alert').val(val);
$('#select_alert').trigger('change'); // вызвать onchange
```

Comment: Да пока помогло, спасибо!